# What's wrong with the rep graph tab?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I just found out the reputation tab on the profile page has this graph feature. I looked at the small graph and saw a high peak in September. I tried to view it by clicking and dragging, but was confronted with a huge peak and no info on what caused it:

[image]

Now this suggested either a huge loss to neutralize the peak (very unlikely), or something wrong with the graph feature. The following picture seems to confirm the second option:

[image]

That is a net gain of +29 rep. However too big the peak in the graph may be, it still is justified. And there is no huge loss to neutralize it. So is there a bug in the graph feature?

**Update**

As comments pointed out, it seems I got two different Sep 24's mixed up. The rep tab picture shows Sep 24 2015, the peak is from 2014. Here is the peak in the rep by time tab:

[image]

Seems the commenter got the peak wrong: 76, not 79 :). Anyways, now the size of the peak in the graph is decidedly appropriate. And the "no net gain" sounds even more absurd.

Comment: What you've highlighted is the peak from September 24, *2014*, where you gained 77 rep. On September 24, 2015, you gained that 29 rep. There's a much smaller peak there.

Comment: Whoops. Well, that strengthens my claim that there is something wrong with that graph thing, since it says "no net gain" :).

Comment: It's an off-by-one error, the graph crossed the date-line.

Comment: @HDE226868 updated Q.

Comment: @DanielFischer you mean the problem is it is looking ad Sep 23 (or 25) instead of 24 because of bad alignment of the graph?

Comment: It seems so. Could be that it's something else, but for the moment I believe it's the same problem.